# Automated Search TimeOut Error when Scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to scrape the data from a specific table and save it into a file that will be filled with the same table from multiple webpages (compounds). However, I'm having difficulties identifying the appropriate table with BeautifulSoup.
Here is the relevant HTML code:

[Table Identifier HTML from Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC8at.png)

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
url2="https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/50-00-0"
r=requests.get(url2)
html=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Gives me an HTML that has only the script: 
"Automated searches: max 1 every 3 seconds. Reloading in 1.  setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true);},1100);"

I believe this is the error in my code, but a websearch turned up no explanation for why this showed up, or how to fix it.
*UPDATE/CONCLUSION: I added driver.implicitly_wait(3) after page loading and after identifying the table to slow down the program. The error has not been replicated.

Comment: looks like the site has some bot detection and it is giving you a message. So do what it suggests: "1 search every 3 seconds"

Comment: This portion of the script is only running a single search for the single table on the single webpage listed, and includes a driver.implicitly_wait(10) after loading the page, and then goes directly into the script above. Is there another way to slow down the bot-scrape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE/CONCLUSION: I added driver.implicitly_wait(3) after page loading and after identifying the table to slow down the program. The error has not been replicated.